# Implicit grant flow in Spring Authorization Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Does implicit grant flow allow in Spring Authorization Server?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to let you know that the implicit grant flow is deprecated nowadays for SPAs. Read here for a summary: https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/articles/oauthoidc/from-implicit-to-pkce.html

Other than that it seems like Spring boot oauth2 supports implict grant flow, see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2-boot-authorization-server-disable

Comment: thank you for your reply. I think that what you mention refers to `Spring Security OAuth` package (org.springframework.security.oauth.boot), this will be on End-Of-Life status as per announcement....What I am after is on the new `Spring Security Authorization` package (org.springframework.security:spring-scurity-oauth2-authorization-server)

Comment: It seems in `Spring Security Authorization`, `implicit` and `password` grants are not supported. Apparently the reason is `Spring Security Authorization`, is built on `OAuth2.1` specs